# What's the difference between BITMAP MERGE and BITMAP OR in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration, sql-tuning

When I check the documentation, I saw that, the BITMAP MERGE performs an OR operation between the bitmaps. So, why there is also a BITMAP OR then? Or, what are the differences between them?

Bests

Comment: What do you mean by `BITMAP OR`? Perhaps this one helps: [Bitmap Index Access Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_optop.htm#TGSQL95195)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are very similar, it's true.

`BITMAP MERGE` takes output from a *single* plan operation that returned multiple bitmaps (e.g, the output of a `RANGE SCAN` operation) and merges those multiple bitmaps into one.

For example, suppose I submit:

```
SELECT 'x'
FROM   t
WHERE  col1 BETWEEN 'A' and 'C'
AND    col2 = 'X';
```

Remember that in a bitmap index, there is a bitmap associated with *each key*.  These are the multiple bitmaps that must be merged.  The plan will look like this:

```
SELECT STATEMENT
  TABLE ACCESS T BY INDEX ROWID
    BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWID
      BITMAP AND
        BITMAP MERGE
          BITMAP INDEX COL1_IDX RANGE SCAN
        BITMAP INDEX COL2_IDX SINGLE VALUE
```

... more or less

In this case, Oracle is scanning the bitmap index on `COL1` to get the distinct index key values between 'A' and 'C'.  Then, it reads the index for the bitmaps associated with each value and merges them together via `OR`.

NOTE: the reason for the `COL2 = 'X'` in the above example is because I *think* Oracle only uses the `BITMAP MERGE` if it needs to generate a single bitmap to pass into a parent step that requires one (in this example, that step is the `BITMAP AND` step).

Contrast that with a `BITMAP OR` plan step.  `BITMAP OR` takes output from *two* plan operations that *each* output a single bitmap.  It that merges those into a single bitmap.

Suppose I submit:

```
SELECT 'x'
FROM   t
WHERE  col1 = 'A'
OR     col2 = 123;
```

Oracle must start with an access path -- a way to use the index to get the data it needs.
In this case the access path will be a `BITMAP INDEX ... SINGLE VALUE` operation on the indexes associated with `COL1` and `COL2`.  It will then use `BITMAP OR` to merge the results of those two access paths.  The plan will look something like this:

```
SELECT STATEMENT
  TABLE ACCESS T BY INDEX ROWID
    BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWID
      BITMAP OR
        BITMAP INDEX COL1_IDX SINGLE VALUE
        BITMAP INDEX COL2_IDX SINGLE VALUE
```

... more or less (I didn't actually test this -- I am just conveying my understanding)